# Text area background color is working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to change background color of a textarea. It is working fine in Chrome but it is not working in Firefox; Even inline CSS is not working in Firefox.

I am customizing bootstrap 4 material kit theme

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide your code or a sample of it reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this,

```
textarea{
 background-color : red;
-moz-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
textarea{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
        some text in the textare
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3805r9q/